# Batch file syntax incorrect

Tags: batch-file, syntax

I am creating a batch file that moves documents from the c drive to a mapped network drive. Here is the output:

> C:\Users\PPC IT Dept\Desktop>move C:\users\my documents\odms\message\foldera*.dss E:\Dest_Folder\
>
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
move "C:\users\my documents\odms\message\foldera*.dss" "E:\Dest_Folder\"
```

If there's a space in your source path you'll need quotes.